# Are unit tests really used as documentation?

Tags: unit-testing, documentation

I cannot count the number of times I read statements in the vein of 'unit tests are a very important source of documentation of the code under test'. I do not deny they are true.

But personally I haven't found myself using them as documentation, ever. For the typical frameworks I use, the method declarations document their behaviour and that's all I need. And I assume the unit tests backup everything stated in that documentation, plus likely some more internal stuff, so on one side it duplicates the documentation while on the other it might add some more that is irrelevant.

So the question is: when are unit tests used as documentation? When the comments do not cover everything? By developers extending the source? And what do they expose that can be useful and relevant that the documentation itself cannot expose?

Comment: Never thought of using unit test straight as documentation. I think the unit tests are often unreadable, because many developers don't take time to write them clearly.

Comment: Comments may be wrong.

Comment: I know you are asking specifically about unit tests, but I'd also note that integration/system tests as really useful documentation too, just at a different level

Comment: @jk. indeed, this question can be generalized to most, if not all, forms of tests

Comment: I've seen unit tests that would be better characterized as “unit experiments”. Their dependence on external factors was just so much as to make them near useless. They were also very unclear. (Yes, I have a long-term goal to refactor them to be better, but I do other things too…)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Code is often wrong too, and not necessarily because it contains bugs; often it's doing entirely the *wrong thing*, but doing it correctly with nicely written unit tests.  Sometimes it's good to have the developer tell you what he thought he was doing in a comment even if he didn't quite manage to pull it off in the code.

Comment: @Ant unit tests invoke the real code and documents the expected response and compare it to the actual response.  Whether the code invoked is correct or not, is not the point - the tests documents how to invoke it.

Comment: @DonalFellows haha, great term, "unit experiments"

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That comment could be a good answer.

Comment: @Ant higher level tests should cover whether the code is doing the right thing though

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### They're NOT an ABSOLUTE Reference Documentation

*Note that a lot of the following applies to comments as well, as they can get out of sync with the code, like tests (though it's less enforceable).*

*So in the end, **the best way to understand code is to have readable working code**.*

<sup>*If at all possible and not writing hard-wired low-level code sections or particularly tricky conditions were additional documentation will be crucial.*</sup>

- Tests can be incomplete:

  - The API changed and wasn't tested,
  - The person who wrote the code wrote the tests for the easiest methods to test first instead of the most important methods to test, and then didn't have the time to finish.
- Tests can be obsolete.
- Tests can be short-circuited in non-obvious ways and not actually executed.

### BUT They're STILL an HELPFUL Documentation Complement

However, when in doubt about what a particular class does, especially if rather lengthy, obscure and lacking comments (you know the kind...), I do quickly try to find its test class(es) and check:

- what they actually try to check (gives a hint about the most important tidbits, except if the developer did the error mentioned above of only implementing the "easy" tests),
- and if there are corner cases.

Plus, if **written using a BDD-style**, they **give a rather good definition of the class's contract**. Open your IDE (or use grep) to see only method names and tada: you have a list of behaviors.

#### Regressions and Bugs Need Tests Too

Also, it's a good practice to write tests for regression and for bug reports: you fix something, you write a test to reproduce the case. When looking back at them, it's a good way to find the relevant bug report and all the details about an old issue, for instance.

I'd say they're a good complement to real documentation, and at least a valuable resource in this regard. It's a good tool, if used properly. If you start testing early in your project, and make it a habit, it COULD be a very good reference documentation. On an existing project with bad coding habits already stenching the code base, handle them with care.

Comment: May I ask why I was downvoted? What ticks you off in there or what do you disagree with?

Comment: The (IMO) best part of your argument is written in the smallest font - the best way to understand code is to have readable code in the first place.  I'd change that to "readable and working code", but I agree.  Then if you look at unit tests again - running tests  are working code (and like all code, should be readable), so it's actually pretty good (if often too local) documentation when done well.

Comment: @MadKeithV: thanks. I updated for "readable and working code" and pushed that bit higher up.

Answer (score 14):

One interpretation is that unit tests are "executable documentation".  You can run the unit tests against the code and it will tell you whether it's still performing as it was when the tests were written to pass, or not.  In that way the unit tests "document" the functionality of the system at some point in time, in an executable way.

On the other hand I have also only rarely actually read unit test code as "documentation" to understand functionality.  A single unit test is too localized, specific and abstract in a way to be able to tell you much about the actual system that's behind the class being tested.

Answer (score 8):

If by documentation you mean *I want something to find out how the code works* then unit tests are perfect little examples of how units of the code works in both *expected*, *edge cases*, and *mistakes* (aka *bugs*) cases.  Also, your tests could be created before the code is written thus underlying what the code should do from a business/requirement point of view.

Are they replacing documentation?  No.

Are they a useful addendum to documentation?  Yes.

Answer (score 6):

I see unit tests as:

- a way to prove the documentation is correct (assuming the documentation matches the api implementation).
- a way to demo to a developer how to use a particular feature; unit test fixtures/unit test themselves are usually small enough that one can quickly learn from it.
- and obviously to spot any regression bug.

To some extend they can be seen as a complement to an existing documentation but not as the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to answer your question by asking you another.

How often when working with a new API/routine have you fired up help to look for a code example of the thing you're trying to use? Failing that you switch over to google for an online search of code samples?

That is exactly when you would use unit tests as documentation.

- In fact the unit tests can be a little more rigorous than normal code examples, because you **should** have multiple tests (examples).
- Hopefully your unit tests illustrate *proper* usage. E.g. They clearly show all essential dependencies either via normal objects or mock objects. (Otherwise they're not particularly good unit tests.)
- NOTE: If your comments or "normal documentation" provides code examples, you're actually violating the DRY principles. And those code examples can easily become **incorrect** over time, whereas there's significantly less chance of that with regularly executed unit tests.
- If the unit tests are thorough (usually a big **if**), then they should provide additional information:

  - All known edge cases clearly illustrated.
  - All expected exceptions that can be thrown.
  - All bugs previously found (this is probably more useful when extending the unit under test than when writing a new client for the unit).
  - All underlying business rules associated with the unit. (if any)

I suspect there are quite a few reasons unit test don't tend to get used as documentation even though they *could* be an excellent complement to more traditional documentation:

- I would venture to suggest that often the tests themselves aren't well enough written for the purpose. Other answers have already alluded to tests that are:

  - Incomplete.
  - Confusing. (I've seen test cases that don't call the method under test directly - you go 3/4 levels deep into the call stack before it's called and the preconditions to calling the method are scattered in different places in a complex class hierarchy.)
  - Outdated. (usually tests *should* fail when they become outdated, but this is not always the case).
- There are usually plenty examples of use already available in production code whenever the need for an example arises.
- The unit under test is so well written (self documenting) that the methods don't need examples. *I wish!*
- In my experience as a programmer, we tend to be quite keen to jump in at the deep end and RTFM *next Tuesday*...
- Documentation and comments that violate the DRY principle.

Comment: `I suspect there are quite a few reasons unit test don't tend to get used as documentation`

One more reason is that comments appear next to the function declaration. Unit tests are in another file that you would have to locate and open. People choose what's closest to reach when consulting the documentation, and that is comments.

Answer (score 3):

*TL;DR Unit tests and API comments are complementary - some things are best described in code, and others in prose.*

Unit tests are mainly useful to document special cases and edge conditions which are hard (and cumbersome) to describe in API comments. Also, the API comments are usually directed to people who want to use the API.

If you want to modify the code, there's typically a lot more you need to know, and some of that is difficult to put into comments (and these comments go stale quickly). In that case a unit test also works as documentation.

An example: You have a method m`(a, b)` that performs a certain calculation. Due to backward compatibility requirements, it must special-case inputs of `a=0` and `a=-1`, but only if `b` is NULL. Putting that into a comment is complicated, verbose, and likely to go stale if the requirement is later removed.

If you make some unit tests that checks the behaviour of `m(0, NULL)`, `m(-1, x)` you get several benefits:

- The description of correct behaviour is clear, misunderstandings are reduced
- People cannot overlook the requirement when they change the code, unlike a comment

Comment: but for your example, if that behaviour is not documented in the comment at all, a user might get unexpected results for that edge case. Which is not exactly a good thing.

Comment: @stijn: True. In that case the best way would probably be to have a brief mention of the special case in the docs, plus the unit tests for the messy details.

Comment: Unit tests are not complimentary - they are mandatory to write (in any rational team)

Answer (score 2):

> For the typical frameworks I use, the method declarations document their behaviour and that's all I need.

Then you've been very lucky to work with frameworks that have descriptive methods and full documentation.

Unit tests are not supposed to be the best form of documentation, but they are a form of documentation whose correctness is immediately verifiable. If your docs go out of date, it might take you a while to spot it, but a unit test would immediately misbehave if the underlying behavior had changed.
Because of that, when a unit test *doesn't* misbehave, you can gain a lot of confidence from knowing that you're looking at an up to date source of information. When I'm reading a manually crafted document, I'm not always as convinced about how correct it is, comparatively speaking.

The point of the advice isn't "forget all other forms of documentation, unit tests tell you everything", but rather that unit tests can be an invaluable source of knowledge on how to interact with a component and what to expect from it.